# In MongoDB, how can I sort a 2d indexed $near query when there are over 100 records?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geolocation, mongodb-query

I have a query that uses `$near` to filter records down to a proximity. It is then supposed to be sorting the results by a separate field. However I'm running into a situation where records are missing even though they match the criteria.

I suspect this is due to the fact that using `$near` with `2d` indexes has a 100 record limit. What I believe is happening is that the geospatial sort is occurring first and mine is only then being applied to the top 100 records of that result.

Is there anyway to overcome this behavior? Can I disregard the sort of `$near` and use my own as the primary sort or, alternatively, circumvent the 100 record limit so that my sort applies to the entire set?

Here is the `explain()` from the query I'm using:

```
db.properties.find({
  loc: { 
    $near: [-80.173366, 34.07868], 
    $maxDistance: 5 
 }}).sort({mls: -1}).explain()

{
    "cursor" : "GeoSearchCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 100,
    "nscannedObjects" : 211,
    "nscanned" : 700,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 211,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 700,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 2,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "slate:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps.. I've used this during a hackaton, so it's been a while:  db.kickstarter.aggregate(   {'$match' : 
                                    {geo2 :
                                        {$geoWithin :
                                            { $centerSphere :[[parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat) ], radius/6371 ] 
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {$sort : {'pledged' : -1}},... etc.

Comment: @Joenesy it does, actually. I was already on my down that path because I just saw this: "$near always returns the documents sorted by distance. Any other sort order requires to sort the documents in memory, which can be inefficient. To return results in a different sort order, use the $geoWithin operator and the sort() method." If you answer the question with that, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: The 100 document limit for `$near` also applies specifically to 2d indexes. If it fits you use case, you could switch to using geoJSON and a 2dsphere index instead of legacy coordinate pairs and a 2d index. Otherwise, use `geoWithin` and your own sort.

Comment: the comment is correct - you should not be using $near unless you want sort by proximity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem a while ago, you can use aggregate - $match. I have used the following Snippet at a hackaton.

```
db.kickstarter.aggregate(   
                            {'$match' : 
                                {geo2 :
                                    {$geoWithin :
                                        { $centerSphere :[[parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat) ], radius/6371 ] 
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {$sort : {'pledged' : -1}},
                            {$limit : 1000}, //you can set your limit here
                            function(err, data){
                                if(err)console.log(err);
                            }
                        );
```